# Parsing URL/web-service

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I made a request to a third party API and it gives me the following response in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<abc>
<xyz>
<code>-112</code>
<message>No such device</message>
</xyz>
</abc>
```

I read this using this code.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("*** url ***");

    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/abc/xyz");
    string code = node.SelectSingleNode("code").InnerText;
    string msg = node.SelectSingleNode("message").InnerText;

    Response.Write("Code: " + code);
Response.Write("Message: "+ msg);
```

But I get an error on this line:

```
string code = node.SelectSingleNode("code").InnerText;
```

Error is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I've run into this a couple of times, mostly it's a namespace issue. Can you elaborate on the format of the XML you receive?

Comment: It means that the previous node (XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/abc/xyz");) was not found. Are you sure the document has no namespace?

Comment: @nonnb Couldn't it also mean that the node "code" was not found, and so he's trying to access the InnerText of a null?

Comment: nonnb it could also mean the node "<code>" is missing, as he is intantly asking the .InnerText of it.

Comment: @Viktor: I assume tags like <abc> and <xyz> are just dummies you used for the purposes of this question. However, in this case it is important to know the tags that are being used, and more specifically, the namespaces in which they are declared.

Comment: @nonnb node `("/abc/xyz");` and node `code` both exist in response. So why i got the error.

Comment: from the error, your node is null, try XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement; XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("./xyz");

Answer (score 6):

I changed the first line of your XML file into:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

to make it valid XML. With this change, your code works for me. Without the change, the parser throws an exception.

Comment: If this is the solution, well spotted sir :-)

Comment: @svinja I am using a third party api. So, how can i can change the xml form.

Comment: @svinja Sorry, I wrote wrong, first line of my xml response is `<?xml version="1.0"?>` but I got the error. Why ??

Comment: My guess would be there is a problem with the "*** url***" part. The only way I can see an exception being thrown only at that point, is if the data at your URL does contain valid XML but without the abc/xyz tag combination. I am guessing the XML you posted is not an accurate representation of your actual XML. Try posting the actual XML and code.

Answer (score 1):

As you've given it, <del>there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code</del> *Edit : Your declaration is wrong, as svinja pointed out, and your xml won't even load into the XmlDocument.*

However, I'm guessing that your xml is more complicated, and there is at least one namespace involved, which would cause the select to fail.

It isn't pretty, but what you can do is use namespace agnostic xpath to locate your nodes to avoid using a `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("*** url ***");

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name()='abc']/*[local-name()='xyz']");
string code = node.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='code']").InnerText;
string msg = node.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='message']").InnerText;

Response.Write("Code: " + code);
Response.Write("Message: "+ msg);
```

**Edit - Elaboration**

Your code works fine if you correct the declaration to `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

However, if you introduce namespaces into the mix, your code will fail unless you use namespace managers appropriately.

My agnostic xpath above will also parse an xml document like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc xmlns="foo">
    <xyz xmlns="bar">
        <code xmlns="bas">-112</code>
        <message xmlns="xyz">No such device</message>
    </xyz>
</abc>
```

Comment: can u elaborate it. I didn't understand. I run your code but it show me the same error

Comment: @Viktor As per svinja's post, your Xml document won't even load as it is. `XmlException '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '?>'.`

Answer (score 1):

**You can use LINQ to XML (if confortable):**

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
  var selectors = (from elements in  doc.Elements("abc").Elements("xyz")
                  select elements).FirstOrDefault();
  string code = selectors.Element("code").Value;
  string msg = selectors.Element("message").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlRoot("abc")]
public class Entity
{
    [XmlElement("xyz")]
    public SubEntity SubEntity { get; set; }
}

public class SubEntity
{
    [XmlElement("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And use standart `xmlserializer`

```
       var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Entity));
       var result = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader("*** url ***"));
       Response.Write("Code: " + result.SubEntity.Code);
       Response.Write("Message: "+ result.SubEntity.Message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<abc>
  <xyz>
    <code>-112</code>
    <message> No such device </message>
  </xyz>
</abc>
```

try to set a list:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/abc/xyz");
```

then read all the nodes and get their text:

```
foreach(XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
  if(node.Name == "code")
  {
    string code = node.InnerText;
  }
  else
  if(node.Name == "message")
  {
    string msg = node.InnerText;
  }
}
```